# When start in dark mode, get NullReferenceException in PlatformConfigurationExtensions.cs

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

By default in my xamarin forms app I have

```
     AppCompatDelegate.DefaultNightMode =AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightNo;
```

But when I start it in dark mode I get the following exception

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sha1.png),

in Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\PlatformConfigurationExtensions.cs

> System.NullReferenceException:'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
> Stacktrace:
> at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PlatformConfigurationExtensions.OnThisPlatform[T] (T element) [0x00000]
> in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\PlatformConfigurationExtensions.cs:8
> at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.FragmentContainer.OnResume () [0x00007]
> in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\FragmentContainer.cs:126
> at AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment.n_OnResume (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00008]
> in D:\a\1\s\generated\androidx.fragment.fragment\obj\Release\monoandroid9.0\generated\src\AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment.cs:2548
> at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.115(intptr,intptr)

It only happens in dark mode, in light mode it init normally.
I was trying to debug but all the threads at that moment are executing external code

Comment: Could you please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via github repo?Also,do you mean the null reference error happens when you switch to `Dark Theme` ?

Comment: it only happens in android 11, comment the code 
AppCompatDelegate.DefaultNightMode =AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightNo; 
 and put background color = white in everything

Comment: You don't provide a sample for me to test so I can't replicate the issue.I think you can try to use `Delegate.SetLocalNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightNo)`;